# Vue.js3: how to filter through nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

I am trying to filter through an Array and inside the main array are other arrays.

I have used `computed` and made a function called `filteredEgg()` I am not sure what I am missing, I am returning the main array and filtering `egg` that is in the array and then creating a short function to return the `name` of the `egg` array

HTML

```
<p v-for="egg in filterEgg(digilist)">{{ egg }}</p>
```

JS

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
data(){
return{
  digilist:[{
            egg:[           
                {
                    id:"blue",
                    eggtype:"blue",
                    name:"Punimon",
                },
        
                {
                    id:"green",
                    eggtype:"green",
                    name:"Botamon",
                },
        
               {
                    id:"orange",
                    eggtype:"orange",
                    name:"Poyomon",
                },
        
                {
                    id:"pink",
                    eggtype:"pink",
                    name:"Yuramon",
                },
    ], 
   baby:[
                
                {
                    id:"botamon",
                    name:"Botamon",
                    stage:"Baby",
                    type:"Data",
                    preDigivolution:["green"],
                    digivolution:["Koromon"],
                    image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"
                },
        
                {
                    id:"poyomon",
                    name:"Poyomon",
                    stage:"Baby",
                    type:"Data",
                    preDigivolution:["orange"],
                    digivolution:["tokomon"],
                    image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/86-poyomon.jpg"
                },
        
                {
                    id:"punimon",
                    name:"Punimon",
                    stage:"Baby",
                    type:"Data",
                    preDigivolution:["blue"],
                    digivolution:["tsunomon"],
                    image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/88-punimon.jpg"
                },
        
                {
                    id:"yuramon",
                    name:"Yuramon",
                    stage:"Baby",
                    type:"Data",
                    preDigivolution:["pink"],
                    digivolution:["tanemon"],
                    image: "https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/123-yuramon.jpg"
                },
    ], 

}]
        }
    }, 

 computed:{
        filteredEgg(digilist){
            return this.digilist.filter((egg) => {
                return egg.name
            })
            }
        },
  
})
```

I have attached a screenshot on what I am trying to achieve, every creature has an evolutionary stage and the filter function is to filter all evolutions that match up to certain creatures example  `eggtype:"blue"` is linekd to `name:"Punimon",` this is just a simple explination as there are a bunch of evolutions and i want to to filtereach egg that links up to each digivolution.

The Data base I created is too big to add here, but you can see it by following this link - https://github.com/SheldonAldridge/Digimon-world-divivolution-guides/blob/main/js/Database/digimon-digivolution-database.js

[image]

Comment: could you show an example of how the end result of the filter function should look?

Comment: Added an example of what I need the function to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all,** you can't pass params to a computed property. There are ways but then the computed lost its reactivity. If you want to work with params, use a function instead. Read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods).

**Second thing,** a computed is used like a property, not a function, so use `filterEgg` instead of `filterEgg()`.

**Last and important**, you don't need to pass anything at all. You already have access to the `digilist` property using `this` instance then why pass it again?

Here is the working demo-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
      <v-app>
        <p v-for="egg in filteredEgg">{{ egg }}</p>
      </v-app>
    </script>
    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template",
        data() {
          return {
            digilist: [{
              egg: [{
                  id: "blue",
                  eggtype: "blue",
                  name: "Punimon",
                },

                {
                  id: "green",
                  eggtype: "green",
                  name: "Botamon",
                },

                {
                  id: "orange",
                  eggtype: "orange",
                  name: "Poyomon",
                },

                {
                  id: "pink",
                  eggtype: "pink",
                  name: "Yuramon",
                },
              ],
            }, ],
          };
        },
        computed: {
          filteredEgg() {
            return this.digilist[0].egg.map((egg) => {
              return egg.eggtype;
            });
          },
        },
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quick Question I get that the above is filtering through the digilist and filtering through it and returning the egg, but is it returning the egg array? is there a way I can check this, usually console.log() would work in Vanilla JS, but not sure how to check that here, because nothing is being rendered on the browser?

Comment: It depends. What is your expected output from `filteredEgg` computed property?

Comment: to get the list of eggs eggtype propert

Comment: Currently computed property will return the array of egg names if you want the array of eggTypes, replace `egg.name` to `egg.eggtype`

Comment: That I understand. the issue is that it's not rendering on the HTML side in the browser. using ``<p v-for="egg in filteredEgg">{{ egg }}</p>``

Comment: I added the code snippet, see if it helps.